# How do I run an Angular Universal app and separate node app for backend api on Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I hope someone out there can help me out!

I have an Angular Universal app which I have deployed to Google App Engine.

I have an app which is running on the default instance of the GAE and it has its own custom domain that I've configured.

So now I want to run a separate node app which is basically just an express server with a mail api endpoint (/api/sendmail) to send mails.

This endpoint will be running on http://localhost:3000/api/sendmail. Below are all my files.

When I hit the endpoint `/api/sendmail`, and I check the logs using gcloud app logs tail -s servicename, it logs out `app.listen(3000, () => { console.log("The server started on port 3000");});`.

But it doesn't seem to run the following. It doesn't run the console log?

```
app.post("/api/sendmail", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Got Request");
}
```

**My package.json has these scripts**

```
"start": "node dist/server",
"deploy": "ng build --prod && npm run build:ssr && gcloud app deploy --quiet && gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml --quiet",
```

**Proxy.conf.json file has this**

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**App.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs10

handlers:
    - url: /.*
      secure: always
      redirect_http_response_code: 301
      script: auto
```

**dispatch.yaml**

```
dispatch:
    - url: "*/api/*"
      service: lunr-app-backend
```

**This is my app.yaml which runs the node app on it's own service**

```
runtime: nodejs10
service: servicename

handlers:
  - url: /api/.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

**My node app has one file: nodemailer.js**

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("The server started on port 3000");
});

app.post("/api/sendmail", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Got Request");
}
```

Please let me know if anyone needs more info. Please check if you see something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing that you're using SSR in your Angular app. I think you need to modify your server.ts file. Please check below code for an example:

https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/d0b4b2a05a9d32c52562cf364261669bffde873c/server.ts#L113